# Could reading data files in R change them?

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

Is it possible that the way most R functions read data files (e.g., .txt, .csv, .sav) could corrupt them or change them in any way? I work in highly collaborative projects and I usually save a copy of the file to make sure I do not accidentally modify them. Is this necessary? 
I am guessing this varies by function. I normally use variations of `read.table()` and `read.spss()` from the `foreign` package.

Thanks!

Comment: Absent a bug, reading a file shouldn't mutate it.

Comment: The data won't change. But some file metadata could change in an OS-dependent manner. Such as "last time file was accessed".

Comment: From my experience, I've got different results while reading `spss` files in R through different libraries. I've stopped my choice on `read_sav` from `haven`, though I had to play for a while to read all `attributes` from spps as I needed them (e.g. labels for factor variables).